# Dictionary or definition of Drupal Commerce Authorize.net payload array

Tags: drupal, payment, authorize.net, commerce

I'm using Drupal commerce and authorize.net for payment. I'm trying to retrieve a few info from the payload array returned by the  authorize.net API, It's an array of 69 elements with numeric indices. 
What I want is a reference or what all the indices stand for here is a sample, pointing me to the right documentation should be enough.

```
    Array
    (
[1501180591] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 1
        [2] => 1
        [3] => This transaction has been approved.
        [4] => C6J5TR
        [5] => Y
        [6] => 40005579354
        [7] => 71
        [8] => 
        [9] => 23.48
        [10] => CC
        [11] => auth_only
        [12] => 1
        [13] => Robin
        [14] => Joe
        [15] => 
        [16] => 534 dash Road
        [17] => Santa Clara
        [18] => CA
        [19] => 93103
        [20] => US
        [21] => 
        [22] => 
        [23] => me@test.com
        [24] => 
        [25] => 
        [26] => 
        [27] => 
        [28] => 
        [29] => 
        [30] => 
        [31] => 
        [32] => 
        [33] => 
        [34] => 
        [35] => 
        [36] => 
        [37] => 71FA3587C4F8704566585B1AED488BF2
        [38] => P
        [39] => 2
        [40] => 
        [41] => 
        [42] => 
        [43] => 
        [44] => 
        [45] => 
        [46] => 
        [47] => 
        [48] => 
        [49] => 
        [50] => XXXX1111
        [51] => Visa
        [52] => 
        [53] => 
        [54] => 
        [55] => 
        [56] => 
        [57] => 
        [58] => 
        [59] => 
        [60] => 
        [61] => 
        [62] => 
        [63] => 
        [64] => 
        [65] => 
        [66] => 
        [67] => 
        [68] => TRUE
        [69] => 
    )
```

)

Comment: You couldn't Google this? It's so easy to find.

Comment: Can you show me a link? Appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```
[0] => ResponseCode
[1] => ResponseSubCode
[2] => ResponseReasonCode
[3] => ResponseReasonText
[4] => AuthorizationCode
[5] => AVSResponse
[6] => TransactionID
[7] => InvoiceNumber
[8] => Description
[9] => Amount
[10] => Method
[11] => TransactionType
[12] => CustomerID
[13] => FirstName
[14] => LastName
[15] => Company
[16] => Address
[17] => City
[18] => State
[19] => ZIPCode
[20] => Country
[21] => Phone
[22] => Fax
[23] => EmailAddress
[24] => ShipToFirstName
[25] => ShipToLastName
[26] => ShipToCompany
[27] => ShipToAddress
[28] => ShipToCity
[29] => ShipToState
[30] => ShipToZIPCode
[31] => ShipToCountry
[32] => Tax
[33] => Duty
[34] => Freight
[35] => TaxExempt
[36] => PurchaseOrderNumber
[37] => MD5Hash
[38] => CardResponseCode
[39] => CardholderAuthenticationVerificationResponse
[40] => unused41
[41] => unused42
[42] => unused43
[43] => unused44
[44] => unused45
[45] => unused46
[46] => unused47
[47] => unused48
[48] => unused49
[49] => unused50
[50] => AccountNumber
[51] => CardType
[52] => SplitTenderID
[53] => RequestedAmount
[54] => BalanceOnCard
[55] => unused56
[56] => unused57
[57] => unused58
[58] => unused59
[59] => unused60
[60] => unused61
[61] => unused62
[62] => unused63
[63] => unused64
[64] => unused65
[65] => unused66
[66] => unused67
[67] => unused68
[68] => unused69
```